# Can't download a file from a link with special character in python

Tags: python, urllib

Simply, I can download a file without any problem with `urllib.request.urlretrieve`. However, if the link has a special character like *, then it doesn't download. Is there a way to bypass special characters in the link?

Comment: Can you show us an examples of the URL. Look at the wget module. It’s eaasier.

Comment: wget  module is also not working. Here is an example of the link: http://xxxxxxxx.us/get.php?username=xxxx&password=xxx**&type=m3u_plus&output=m3u8

Comment: hello, I am sorry that did not work. Unfortunately, the link you sent did not open could update your question with actual source code or comment a working link?

Comment: Hi again. Unfortunately I cannot give the exact link since it contains username and password. I tried to download the same link via wget module on win 10 and it worked. At the moment, I cannot download the link on ubuntu with either urllib or wget. Can it be something os related?

Comment: As far as I believe it’s independent on the os. I have used them on both. Could you confirm that you have the module installed.

Comment: I have the module installed. But it seems that the problem is not special character in the link as I initially stated. Both a python script with wget module and wget command line tool throw the same 403 error in ubuntu. On windows, they are both fine and just downloads without any error.

Comment: So when I used the whet module to download online data, my network server was not secure I.e. did not require the input of credentials.

Comment: But on the other hand, I have worked on systems which require credentials just like in your case. See my answer for the solution I used.

Answer (score 0):

I’m not sure if this will work, but have you tried the ampersand code for asterisk?

`&#42`

List of codes: https://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html-spec/html-spec_13.html

Answer (score 0):

Please be advised that the code below will be used to access a FTP server to download data .

```
from ftplib import FTP

with FTP('put your server address here') as ftp:
    ftp.login(user=username,passwd=password)
    ftp.retrbinary("URL","Local_file path")
```

Let me know if this somehow relates to your problem and if it lets.

Comment: The server is not an ftp server and that's why your code unfortunately didn't work. And the link is an iptv playlist with file type m3u. It also seems the server uses cloudflare. This might be the reason.